# How to get cell value by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a problem that I can't solve how much I try. By clicking on the *Edit Customer* button I wan't to get the value from the *CustomerNr* cell. My problem is that I don't know how to get the row index by clicking on a button and then pass it to my function so I can specifically get the CustomerNr on that row I pressed the button on. You can take a look at my jsfiddle link and note, this is the first time I code in Javascript/Jquery. I'm open for smart solutions.

Here you can see how far I came. I managed to select value from a specific cell.

```
function GetCellValues() {
    var Row = document.getElementById("somerow");
    var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
    alert(Cells[0].innerText);

}
```

I have managed to get the row index by clicking on on a **td** but I want to get it by pressing a button.

```
function myMethod(obj) {
    alert(obj.parentNode.rowIndex); // parentNode is also used
}
```

I wan't to somehow combine this two functions, like in C#. (I'm a C# programmer)

```
function GetCellValues(e) {
    //Something here
    alert(Cells[0].Rows[e] innerText);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6srjc7qL/

Comment: you can pass the trigger to the handler, and then use parentNode to reach the td and tr: http://jsfiddle.net/6srjc7qL/3/

Comment: @dandavis Yes the button is in a cell between <td>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the id's of your buttons to classes, as you can't name two elements with the same id, then I looped through the elements... [**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6srjc7qL/7/)

You should avoid to use inline functions and pereferably do it like this, this might safe you a lot of time and keeps it better maintainability:

Javascript:

```
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('otherButton');

for (var i = 0; i<a.length;i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener('click',function(){

     var b = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].textContent;
    alert(b);


    });


}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="somerow">
        <tr>
            <th>CustomerNr</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Cigarettes Inc</td>
            <td>Rambo</td>
            <td>
                <button class="otherButton" >Edit Customer</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >22</td>
            <td>Razor</td>
            <td>David</td>
            <td>
                <button class="otherButton">Edit Customer</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>H&M</td>
            <td>Samuel Adams</td>
            <td>
                <button class="otherButton" >Edit Customer</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

}
```

Answer (score 2):

the button is inside the td which is inside the tr, so you need to go 2 nodes up. Try this:

```
function GetCellValues(obj) {

    alert(obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);

}
```

Comment: that's doesn't work without modifying the code upstream to pass an element, right now, obj would be undefined. see my fiddle for a correctly-working example

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <style>
            table, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            .selected {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <table id="somerow">
                <tr>
                    <th>CustomerNr</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Cigarettes Inc</td>
                    <td>Rambo</td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="otherButton" onclick="GetCellValues()">Edit Customer</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td onclick="myMethod(this);">22</td>
                    <td>Razor</td>
                    <td>David</td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="otherButton" onclick="GetCellValues()">Edit Customer</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>H&M</td>
                    <td>Samuel Adams</td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="otherButton" onclick="GetCellValues()">Edit Customer</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </center>
    </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
function GetCellValues(elm) {
    alert(elm.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].textContent);
}

function myMethod(obj) {
    alert(obj.parentNode.rowIndex);
}
```